# Facebook web application getting Acess Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a web application using php. I have a closed group in facebook. When a user login to my application I am showing them a page. I want to stream data grom my facebook group and display in that page. Since this is a closed group I am not able to stream data from that using php SDK. I am using the following code.

This code workes if the group is public.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => FB_APP_ID, 'secret' => FB_SECRET_KEY, 'cookie' => true,));
return $facebook->api('/' . FB_GROUP_ID . '/feed');
```

I think that we have to pass access token with extended permission to get that data. But how to generate that token without user intevention ?

Any Ideas?

Comment: I am thinking of generating a long lived access token manually and storing it in database. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, that will work – as long as the user you acquired the token with does not change their password; then you will have to go through this process again. Could be a little more convenient if you had a little admin interface for that, where the user can just connect to your app, and have it get the access token programmatically and store it to your config.

Comment: But when the token expires we have to update the token manually. That is a problem I think. Also now facebook offline access is deprecated. So the access token will expire after 60 days :(

Comment: Yeah, right – there does not seem to be a thing as non-expiring page access tokens for groups yet. So that’d be one more reason for having an admin interface where a new access token can be acquired and saved to the config quickly. And maybe you want to set up a cronjob or something that notifies the admin a few days before the token expires, so he can set a new one in time.